# Capturing everything in brackets while discarding the rest

Tags: regex

I'm using Regex and substitution but having a problem with the different formats which one regular expression fits all the strings. I want to be able to capture everything within square brackets, then circle brackets then curley brackets "{}", I've tried capturing whats in the square brackets first then setting up the other unwanted text in the string as other capture groups but it only works for a specific format. 
For example these strings I want a single regex to work for all of them:

Example 1:

```
"(text 1) (text 2) [text 3] [text4] {text 5} {text6} text7 text 8 text9 text10"
```

Wanted result:

```
"text 3, text4"
```

Example 2:

```
"(text 1) [text2] [text3] [text4] text 5 text6"
```

Wanted result:

```
"text2, text3, text4"
```

Example 3:

```
"[text2] [text3] {text4} text5 text6 text7 text8"
```

Wanted result:

```
"text2, text3"
```

Example 4:

```
"{text1} {text2} text3"
```

Wanted result:

```
""
```

Example 5:

```
"[text1] text2"
```

Wanted result:

```
"text1"
```

Example 6:

```
"[text1]"
```

Wanted result:

```
"text1"
```

The result I'm looking for is eveything within the square brackets be captured and everything else not to be used. Then using a second and third regex that does the same thing but captures whats in the circle brackets and then curley brackets instead.

I've tried using `"\[(.+?|)\]"` but it only manages to capture and group but not discard the rest of the string.

Comment: Would `(?<=\[)[^\]]*` do the [trick](https://regex101.com/r/rDdf5k/1)?

Comment: You get all the matches with `\[([^\]\[]+)\]`, grab Group 1 values and join the found matches with `,` + space. What is your programming language?

Comment: using regex for renaming and capturing text to import to other fields. Tried both the regex but it also includes the uncaptured text outside the brackets. I'm using substitution.

Comment: *I'm using Regex* does not help. Where are you using it? Show the code.

Comment: I'm using it with hydrus, for automatic tagging. regex101.com in the first comment is where I can test out the string first to see if it works in the program. The first comment https://regex101.com/r/rDdf5k/1 show under the substitution that it has captured and remove all within square brackets, where I want it to do the opposite. Keep whats in the square brackets and discard the rest.

Comment: Try `\[(.*?)\]|[^\]\[]+` and replace with `$1\n`

Comment: Forgot to say its using python flavour with the regex. It returns a line of "$1"

Comment: Then use `\1\n` in the replacement

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=\])
```

with "global" option, to match all occurrences.

Details:

- `(?<=\[)` - positive lookbehind for `[`.
- `[^\]]+` - a non-empty sequence of chars other than `]` - the content to
  be matched.
- `(?=\])` - positive lookahead for `]`.

You don't even need any capturing group.
Just read consecutive matches (getting a list of strings) and create the
result joining them with a comma and space (between each pair of matches).

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/reMzWl/1

Answer (score 0):

Try [(.*?)]|[^][]+ and replace with $1\n – Wiktor Stribiżew 
\1\n

thanks for the help